# How to check if a Thread in a thread pool is actually working long or blocked or stuck for any reason?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I launch threads as:

```
ScheduledExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(workerCount);
threadPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new WorkerThread("<required info for worker>"), 1, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
threadPool.awaitTermination(-1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I need to see periodically if any `WorkerThread` is 'stuck' during processing a long task or it's really proceeding with the work.
If it's stuck, I would need to kill/stop that thread and put the work item in the work queue again so that another WorkerThread could pick it up.

In my case, `WorkerThread` is actually loading a large document from Elasticsearch.

Comment: You can't really kill/stop a thread. The stop method has been deprecated forever. What you can do is interrupt it (which will wake it up if it is waiting or doing I/O), but that requires cooperation from the thread itself. It needs to handle the interrupt and exit. As for checking status, communicate using a shared object using synchronized methods or Atomic fields. Update the object from the worker and check last updated timestamp from the outside.

Comment: @ewramner A working thread is already busy / stuck. How would it update its status by calling something on a shared object? Even if the worker thread is active, how would it periodically update something apart from it's task?

Comment: It depends on the task.  If the task can generate any error condition, it's up to the task to report the error and stop on its own.  How does some supertask ensure that an arbitrary task is running properly or needs to abend?

Comment: In embedded software, we use something called a [_watchdog_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer). It's a hardware timer that resets the whole system if the application fails to periodically reset the watchdog. The software equivalent would be a thread that wakes up periodically to look for signs of "progress." That could be as simple as a boolean flag. The watchdog thread could clear the flag before each time it goes to sleep, and expect the flag to be set when it wakes again. If the flag isn't set, then the watchdog knows that something's gone wrong, and it takes corrective action.

Comment: ...But +1 for what ewramner said: You can't _generally_ fix a problem by killing a stuck thread. Once the thread is stuck, then the state of the entire process is suspect. (That's why `Thread.stop()` and `Thread.suspend()` are deprecated.) You usually need to kill the whole process at that point, and if the process has persistent data, then you may need to run a consistency check on it before the new process resumes work.

Comment: The working thread may not be busy on CPU. If it is, no luck, but if it blocks on I/O (networking, files) every now and then a Thread.interrupt() will cause that to fail, and the worker can detect that it should stop and abort. As for updating status, it needs to do that regularly as part of the normal code. This assumes you can modify the worker code. If you can't, there really is no good solution in Java.

Comment: @ewramner updated my question to indicate that the `WorkerThread` is actually loading a large document from the Elasticsearch.

Comment: If "loading" means "getting over the network" then Thread.interrupt() should be able to stop it. If it means "parsing and converting from bytes to objects after having fetched the data" then it is CPU bound and interrupt won't help.